# Libtorch build failed. In "qlinear_unpack.cpp", a class has no member "unpack"

Tags: c++, makefile, pytorch, libtorch

Update: 
I tried v1.1.0 source that my teammate downloaded before, then this problem disappeared. It seems that the master branch(190604) has the following issue. Try tag v1.1.0 instead of master.

---

I downloaded pytorch source to build libtorch from github. Using following command:

```
git clone [pytorch git] --recursive
```

Then run

```
python setup.py build
```

Then get following error msgs:

```
[ 46%] Building CXX object caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2.dir/__/aten/src/TH/THTensorMoreMath.cpp.o
/home/in4ight/libtorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/quantized/cpu/qlinear_unpack.cpp: In member function ‘at::Tensor at::native::{anonymous}::QLinearUnpackWeightInt8::operator()(at::Tensor)’:
/home/in4ight/libtorch/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/quantized/cpu/qlinear_unpack.cpp:37:12: error: ‘class fbgemm::PackBMatrix<signed char>’ has no member named ‘unpack’
     packB->unpack(weight_ptr_int8);
```

How to build libtorch correctly?